# cicle if-do while not working, but seems perfect

Tags: c#, if-statement, counter, do-while, break

im doing a "winners table", from a excel page, this cicle is to find the winner:

```
            if (G1 != "0")
            {
                do
                {
                    D1 = dgv1.Rows[con].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString();
                    D2 = dgv1.Rows[con].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString();
                    D3 = dgv1.Rows[con].Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString();
                    D4 = dgv1.Rows[con].Cells[3].FormattedValue.ToString();

                    if (D1 == G1)
                    {
                        TablaGanadores.Rows.Add(D1.ToString(), D2.ToString(), D3.ToString(), D4.ToString());
                        break;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        con++;
                    }


                }
                while (con < 999);
            }
```

There are a Textbox where you put the winner number, it's default valor is "0", that's why if G1 (the number in Textbox) is not 0, it will continue doing the cicle "Do-While", there i put in D1,D2,D3,D4 the data from 1 row in excel page (they work alone outside the cicle), then the cicle, if D1 (where is the number to compare) is the same as the winner number in the Textbox, it will create a new row in my table "TablaGanadores", with D1,D2,D3,D4 (it works outside of cicle), then, it breaks the cicle, else, just add 1 to my counter, to check the next row in my excel file, and there are 999 rows

But it just don't work, and im in my limit day to give my program, and this is the last thing in it, my head will explode, i don't find the error

Comment: "It just don't work" doesn't tell us much about the problem.  This is a *great* opportunity for you to start using a debugger.  With a debugger (all versions of Visual Studio have one built in) you can place a breakpoint in the code and pause on that line during execution.  Then you can step through the code, one line at a time, as it runs.  Doing this allows you to observe the exact behavior, observe your variables and how each line changes them, etc.  When you do this, what specific line of code first produces an unexpected result?  What was the result?  What did you expect?  Why?

Comment: What do you mean it' doesn't work? What exactly is your expected output, and how is your result different?

Comment: there is in the description, I need the program to put a row in my table, with the winning number, but the cicle  don't do that, in a textbox you put the winner number, 
the number in the textbox is stored in "G1", the default number in textbox is 0, so, 
if you haven't put anything, the cicle won't do anything, but if you put a numer, the cicle will run, then, in D1,D2,D3,D4 i put the first row if my excel file, the D1 contains the number to check, then, if G1 and D1 is the same, it will create a new row in my table "TablaGanadores", with D1,D2,D3,D4 (it works outside of cicle),

Comment: then, it breaks the cicle, else, just add 1 to my counter, to check the next row in my excel file, and there are 999 rows

Comment: i just need that the cicle add a new row in my DataGridView with the info of the winner number, stored in D1,D2,D3, D4

Comment: but well, i will use the debugger, i never used it, probably i will find why it doesn't work, maybe, thanks